# Symfony2 - generate csv from string and force file download

Tags: php, symfony, csv, http

How to implement similar solution as this:

```
$file = generateCSV();
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="asd");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $file;
exit();
```

using Symfony Response object?

Right now I have

```
    $file = generateCSV();
    $response = new Response($file);
    $response->headers->makeDisposition(ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT, 'asd');
    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'text/csv');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma', 'no-chache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires', '0');
    return $response;
```

but it doesn't seem to work because instead of sending file to download it renders my file as text in browser.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify content type. My download example:

```
$dispositionHeader = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
            ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
            $filename . '.csv'
        );

$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
$response->headers->set('Pragma', 'public');
$response->headers->set('Cache-Control', 'maxage=1');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $dispositionHeader);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done this like this :

```
$response = new StreamedResponse();
    $response->setCallback(

     /* here you generate your csv file */

    );

    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    $response->headers->set(
        'Content-Disposition',
        'attachment; filename="file.csv"'
    );

    return $response;
```